# Cannot compile unisim code in iverilog

Tags: verilog, xilinx, icarus

I have been trying to compile ICAP_SPARTAN6.v from the unisim librabries provided by xilinx using icarus verilog.

I get the compile error below:

```
/opt/Xilinx/14.3/ISE_DS/ISE/verilog/src/unisims/ICAP_SPARTAN6.v:79: syntax error
/opt/Xilinx/14.3/ISE_DS/ISE/verilog/src/unisims/ICAP_SPARTAN6.v:79: error: invalid module item.
```

The relevent lines of code referred to is below:

```
  tri (weak1, strong0) done_o = p_up;//line 78
  tri (pull1, supply0) [15:0] di_t = (icap_idone == 1 && WRITE == 1)? 16'bz : dix; //line 79
```

I would also like to note that I am not very clear how tri works exactly. I assumed that it is similar to a wire except has 3 states but the paranthesis following it does not make sense to me and that makes debugging a little harder :)
Any help would be appreciated. -Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tri` and `wire` are equivalent.

The keywords in parentheses determine drive strength, which allows switch and gate-level modeling. The rules are somewhat complex but basically a stronger signal can override a weaker one so driving a `pull1` and `strong0` on the same signal may result in a `0` state, rather than `X` or `Z`.

The error looks like a bug or missing feature in iverilog. Removing the vector range allows a successful compile.

Comment: Thanks. It was easier for me to resolve the issue with your explanation. I changed the code to make two wires one for each driver. I then made a wire to resolve the two drivers by anding them - since supply0 is the stronger signal if either driver has 0 the resolved signal will be 0. If either driver is z or X I drive the resolved signal to the value of the other signal. I am yet to run my  change to see if it causes any simulation issues, but it compiles now :)